# Keeping property of autocomplete when adding row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic, row

Hello I have some input who I use autocomplete but I have a add row but when I'm adding row I don't have the option of autocomplete. How I do autocomplete on my new row?

Here how I do my autocomplete :

```
//------------------AUTO COMPLETE NUMÉRO DE PROJET----------------------    
            $(document).ready(function(){

        //-------AUTO COMPLETE DIMANCHE PROJET-----
                $("#projdim").autocomplete({
                    source:'getautocomplete.php',
                    minLength:1
```

if enter is pressed

```
//------------------COMPLETE CLIENT DESC DIMANCHE----------------------
                function handleEnter(e, obj, field){

                    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                          }
                        else
                          {// code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                          }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                          {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                {
                                    tempArrayInJS = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                                    $("#clientdim").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']);
                                    $("#prodescdim").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['proDescription']);
                                }
                          }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","completeclient.php?q="+obj.value,true);
                        xmlhttp.send();

                    }
                    //Enter was pressed, handle it here

                    }
```

Here is my input original

```
<span id="numpro" > 
    <input onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" type="text" id="projdim" name="projdim"onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, this, 'task');"/>  
</span>
```

Here how I add row

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['Terminé'])) { ?>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post"  >
            <b>Dimanche</b> </br><?php echo $date1 ?>
            <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>add</span>  </a></p>

        </td>   
My JS of adding row
<script type="text/javascript">


    var counter = 0;
    $(function(){
        $('p#add_field').click(function(){
            counter += 1;
            $('#numpro').append(
                    '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text"  />'
                    );
            $('#proclient').append(

                    '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfieldstest[]' + '" type="text" /><br />'
                    );  


        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're only adding autocomplete to elements with id `projdim`. You need to run the autocomplete function on every element you want it to effect. For example, change your append function to

```
$('p#add_field').click(function(){
            counter += 1;
            var $newRow = $('<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text"  />');
            $('#numpro').append($newRow);
            $newRow.autocomplete(autocompOpt);
            ...
```

`autocompOpt` here is an object representing your autocomplete options. In the code you gave, something like

```
var autocompOpt = {
    source:'getautocomplete.php',
    minLength:1
}
```

Comment: big thanks but How I do cause usualy I press enter for complete input client and description